# Sorting SLURM sreport by gres not working

Tags: slurm

I want to see the gres usage by user on the SLURM cluster I am managing. The issue is that I cannot get it sorted according to this usage, it gets sorted by cpu usage (or billing?) According to https://slurm.schedmd.com/sreport.html  TopUsage "... users are sorted by CPUTime, but the -T, --tres option will sort users by the first TRES specified." But the output I get is

```
sreport  user  -t hourper TopUsage TopCount=5 --tres=gres/gpu:tesla start=2021-05-01T00:00:00 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 5 Users 2021-05-01T00:00:00 - 2021-09-28T23:59:59 (13046400 secs)
Usage reported in TRES Hours/Percentage of Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster     Login     Proper Name         Account      TRES Name              Used 
--------- --------- --------------- --------------- -------------- ----------------- 
    bayes   a               a               student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes   b               b               student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes   c               c               student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes   d               d               student gres/gpu:tesla          2(0.05%) 
    bayes   e               e               student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%)
```

If I also add cpu to the tres I get

```
sreport  user  -t hourper TopUsage TopCount=5 --tres=gres/gpu:tesla,cpu start=2021-05-01T00:00:00 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 5 Users 2021-05-01T00:00:00 - 2021-09-28T23:59:59 (13046400 secs)
Usage reported in TRES Hours/Percentage of Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster     Login     Proper Name         Account      TRES Name              Used 
--------- --------- --------------- --------------- -------------- ----------------- 
    bayes         a               a         student            cpu      13786(1.59%) 
    bayes         a               a         student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes         b               b         student            cpu      13509(1.55%) 
    bayes         b               b         student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes         c               c         student            cpu       6134(0.71%) 
    bayes         c               c         student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%) 
    bayes         d               d         student            cpu       2792(0.32%) 
    bayes         d               d         student gres/gpu:tesla          2(0.05%) 
    bayes         e               e         student            cpu       1585(0.18%) 
    bayes         e               e         student gres/gpu:tesla          0(0.00%)
```

Any ideas of how I can get this to sort properly?